# How to set validation language depending on user type Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have three user types in my application and if the user type is user, validation messages should be English, otherwise if admin or a company, it should be Japanese.

In my `app.php` file I do:

```
'locale' => 'en',
'fallback_locale' => 'ja',
```

And in my `web.php` file:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:user'], function () {
    App::setLocale('en');
    //user controllers
});

Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:company'], function () {
    App::setLocale('ja');
    //company controllers
});

Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:admin'], function () {
    App::setLocale('ja');
    //admin controllers
});
```

When I didn't set the locale language of admin to `ja`, validation of user is English and the same with the admin and company. Now I set locale of admin and company to `ja`, the validation messages of users are now also Japanese. This is the validation files languages directory.

[image]

I really run out of ideas where to strike this one out and any help is appreciated. I've tried the suggested solutions in the web but nothing is working.

Comment: Anyone who has an idea on this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably add some kind of language switcher support.

Maybe like this: https://github.com/akaunting/language

Or if you want simpler solution just create small middleware that will change locale on the fly depends on user settings/access role/etc.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use App;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class SetLocaleForAdmin
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            if(in_array(Auth::user()->email, ['admin@site.com','admin2@site.com','admin3@site.com'])) {
                App::setLocale('ja');
            }
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Don't forget to add middleware to web group in `Kernel.php`

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
   'web' => [
        ...
        \App\Http\Middleware\SetLocaleForAdmin::class,
        ...
    ],
];
```

Comment: Thanks for this one, but I have tried reproducing it but still doesn't work. :(

Comment: @EemJee why it doesn't work?) Updated answer, added simple middleware example which should work for you. Just add check for admins.

Comment: Just the same result.

Comment: @EemJee Did you remove setLocale from routes in web.php?

Comment: Yes, I think I have to dig deeper with this.

Comment: @EemJee how do you test it then? If you logged as admin user you will see anything in japanese, other users will see default english.

Comment: Yes. Admin and company owners will see it as Japanese and users will see english. Should I call this in my web.php? if so, how?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189107/discussion-between-sanasol-and-eem-jee).